# How to use timestamps from Bloomberg quotes

Tags: unix, math, time

For the past couple of weeks I have been working on building a stock program. Everything has been going great but one thing I have learned is getting clear and exact times is a extremely hard thing to do.

I got permission from bloomberg.com to pull there data and they give me prices by one minute ticks throughout the day witch is amazing the only problem is they claim there data is organized by time and by unix time at that witch I looked up starts on January 1 1970 and has a lot of other really wired things.

But long story short if you visit the page below as a example and look at there ticks markets you can see that we have a open time of 1377077400000

(http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/AAPL:US)

Witch is great but here is my issue. That dosnt convert correctly it should come out to August 21st 2013 at 06:30AM but when I use wolf ram alpha 
(http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=convert+August+21st+2013+06%3A30AM+to+Unix+Time)
I get this number 
1377091800

This is puzzling I think its due to a time zone difference between phoenix and new york but im not sure can someone please help

Thank you

Comment: It is just the number of milliseconds since Jan 1 1970 UTC. It shouldn't be that hard to calculate a (local) datetime from that. What language/technique are you using?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things going on here:

`1377077400000` appears to be given in milliseconds, not seconds. Trim off three zeros and Wolfram will give you `9:30 AM UTC, August 21, 2013`.

Which leads us to the next issue:

Bloomberg's timestamp appears to be in eastern local time, because 9:30 AM UTC+0 is certainly not the daily opening of the NYSE. So you'll have to treat that timestamp as a local time, not the more usual UTC+0 timestamp. If converting back to UTC+0, be mindful of EST vs. EDT.